# Php append value to an exsisting array

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I need to add some value-key pair to an array which is the output of mysql query. Below is the code,

```
 $query = "select TITLE,DESCRIPTION from  TABLE where ID='1234'";
 $result  = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($numrows>0)
 {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $myArray[] = $row;
 }
}

echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Giving me the result like

```
[{"TITLE":"Special","DESCRIPTION":"This is DESCRIPTION."}]
```

Now I need to to add an another key-value pair to generate the json output like,

```
[{"TITLE":"Special","DESCRIPTION":"This is DESCRIPTION.","URL":"imgname.jpg"}]
```

So I added the code

```
$myArray["URL"]="imgname.jpg";
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

But giving me the output like,

```
{"0":{"TITLE":"Chef Special","DESCRIPTION":"Grilled Salmon and crab."},"URL":"imgname.jpg"}
```

Is there anything wrong with above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your data with

```
var_dump($myArray);
```

and you will find, that it is a 2-dimensional array. you'd have to add your data with

```
$myArray[0]["URL"] = "imgname.jpg";
```

Comment: one maxime of debugging data structures: "when in doubt - print it out"

Answer (score 1):

If you have to add after encoding it, reverse with:

```
$a = json_decode($myArray,true)
```

add a new pair of *key, value* with `$a['URL'] = "imgname.jpg"` and then encode again.